# how does unit testing works in django? (with coverage)

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, code-coverage

i am finding it kinda confusing to do unit testing especially with fields that has blank=True attribute or unique=True

look at this for example:

```py
class TagTest(TestCase):
    def create(self):
        tag = models.Tag.objects.create(name='test')
        return tag
    def test_get(self):
        tag = self.create()
        self.assertIsInstance(tag, models.Tag)
        self.assertEqual(tag.name, tag.__str__())
        self.assertEqual(len(tag.name),4)class TagTest(TestCase):
    def create(self):
        tag = models.Tag.objects.create(name='test')
        return tag
    def test_get(self):
        tag = self.create()
        self.assertIsInstance(tag, models.Tag)
        self.assertEqual(tag.name, tag.__str__())
        self.assertEqual(len(tag.name),4)
```

look at coverage for example, it is telling me i am not covering the test case at all

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was because i needed to "run" coverage before actually generating html, so firstly:
`coverage run manage.py test app_name`

then:
`coverage html`

to generate new html.